# How do I use a tkinter button with a function, using variables from tk.Entry?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to write some simple code to put variables into a simple function, that uses temperature and pressure to calculate an output called fO2.

I can't see how to update the input variables, right now it uses 0.
Also whatever you enter into `Temp_input` is duplicated in `P_input`.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import *
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk  
   
   
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Oxygen Fugacity')
root.geometry("500x400")

Temp_input = tk.Entry(root, width=15, borderwidth=5,textvariable=Tcinput)
Temp_input.grid(row=1,column=1)
P_input = tk.Entry(root, width=15, borderwidth=5,textvariable=Pinput)
P_input.grid(row=2,column=1)

Templabel = tk.Label(root,text='Temperature (C)').grid(row=1,column=0)
Plabel = tk.Label(root,text='Pressure (bar)').grid(row=2,column=0)

comp = tk.Button(root, text='Compute', command=lambda: all).grid(row=3,column=1)

Tcinput = tk.IntVar(master=root,value=Tcinput).get()
Pinput = tk.IntVar(master=root,value=Pinput).get()

tk.Label(root, text='NNO').grid(row=1,column=3,padx=(30,0),pady=(10,10))
tk.Label(root, text='FMQ').grid(row=2,column=3,padx=(30,0),pady=(10,10))
tk.Label(root, text='IW').grid(row=3,column=3,padx=(30,0),pady=(10,10))
tk.Label(root, text='MH').grid(row=4,column=3,padx=(30,0),pady=(10,10))
tk.Label(root, text='CoCoO').grid(row=5,column=3,padx=(30,0),pady=(10,10))
tk.Label(root, text='CCO').grid(row=6,column=3,padx=(30,0),pady=(10,10))

NNO_OUT = tk.Message(root, text = all(Tcinput,Pinput)[0]).grid(row=1,column=4,padx=(30,0))
FMQ_OUT = tk.Message(root, text = all(Tcinput,Pinput)[1]).grid(row=2,column=4,padx=(30,0))
IW_OUT = tk.Message(root, text = all(Tcinput,Pinput)[2]).grid(row=3,column=4,padx=(30,0))
MH_OUT = tk.Message(root, text = all(Tcinput,Pinput)[3]).grid(row=4,column=4,padx=(30,0))
CoCoO_OUT = tk.Message(root, text = all(Tcinput,Pinput)[4]).grid(row=5,column=4,padx=(30,0))
CCO_OUT = tk.Message(root, text = all(Tcinput,Pinput)[5]).grid(row=6,column=4,padx=(30,0))

root.mainloop()

def all(Tc=1200,P=1):
    a = str(round(fo2.NNO(Tc,P),2))
    b = str(round(fo2.FMQ(Tc,P),4))
    c = str(round(fo2.IW(Tc,P),4))
    d = str(round(fo2.MH(Tc,P),4))
    e = str(round(fo2.CoCoO(Tc,P),4))
    f = str(round(fo2.CCO(Tc,P),4))
    x=[a,b,c,d,e,f]
    return x
```

EDIT

Ive edited the code and the button still doesn't work, I've tried to play around with lambda and ()'s on the functions

can anyone see a problem?

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import *
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk  

   
def some_func():
    global Tcinput, Pinput
    Tc = Tcinput.get() #  GETTER
    P = Pinput.get() #  GETTER
    a = str(round(fo2.NNO(Tc,P),4))
    b = str(round(fo2.FMQ(Tc,P),4))
    c = str(round(fo2.IW(Tc,P),4))
    d = str(round(fo2.MH(Tc,P),4))
    e = str(round(fo2.CoCoO(Tc,P),4))
    f = str(round(fo2.CCO(Tc,P),4))
    x=[a,b,c,d,e,f]
    return x
   
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Oxygen Fugacity')
root.geometry("500x400")

Tcinput = tk.IntVar(master=root,value=1200)  # NEW
Pinput = tk.IntVar(master=root,value=1)   # NEW
Temp_input = tk.Entry(root, width=15, borderwidth=5,textvariable=Tcinput)
Temp_input.grid(row=1,column=1)
P_input = tk.Entry(root, width=15, borderwidth=5,textvariable=Pinput)
P_input.grid(row=2,column=1)

Templabel = tk.Label(root,text='Temperature (C)').grid(row=1,column=0)
Plabel = tk.Label(root,text='Pressure (bar)').grid(row=2,column=0)

tk.Label(root, text='NNO').grid(row=1,column=3,padx=(30,0),pady=(10,10))
tk.Label(root, text='FMQ').grid(row=2,column=3,padx=(30,0),pady=(10,10))
tk.Label(root, text='IW').grid(row=3,column=3,padx=(30,0),pady=(10,10))
tk.Label(root, text='MH').grid(row=4,column=3,padx=(30,0),pady=(10,10))
tk.Label(root, text='CoCoO').grid(row=5,column=3,padx=(30,0),pady=(10,10))
tk.Label(root, text='CCO').grid(row=6,column=3,padx=(30,0),pady=(10,10))

comp = tk.Button(root, text='Compute', command=lambda: some_func()).grid(row=3,column=1)

NNO_OUT = tk.Message(root, text = some_func()[0]).grid(row=1,column=4,padx=(30,0))
FMQ_OUT = tk.Message(root, text = some_func()[1]).grid(row=2,column=4,padx=(30,0))
IW_OUT = tk.Message(root, text = some_func()[2]).grid(row=3,column=4,padx=(30,0))
MH_OUT = tk.Message(root, text = some_func()[3]).grid(row=4,column=4,padx=(30,0))
CoCoO_OUT = tk.Message(root, text = some_func()[4]).grid(row=5,column=4,padx=(30,0))
CCO_OUT = tk.Message(root, text = some_func()[5]).grid(row=6,column=4,padx=(30,0))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Move the definition of `all` to the top (just after the imports) and change `command=lambda: all` to `command=lambda: all(...)` with the correct arguments

Comment: Note that the `grid()` method ***always*** returns `None`, so that is the value that will be assigned to all those `*_OUT` variables immediately before the call to `mainloop()`.

Comment: Also you defined `all` after you used it in all of those `tk.Message`s. That means that it will be using python's built in `all` function instead of the one you defined.

Comment: …which is why you should avoid naming your own functions the same as built-ins.

Comment: @TheLizzard Ive moved the some_func definition up and the button still doesn't work, I've tried messing around with lambda and using ()'s on the function, which some of the answers to this problem have suggested. Any more ideas? cheers again :)

Comment: @EdwardBaker The reason it doesn't work is because you call `some_func` (here: `NNO_OUT = tk.Message(..., text=some_func()[0]).grid(...)`) before the user has a chance to write anything inside `tk.Entry`s. I have no idea what you are trying to do and I haven't used `tk.Message` so I can't help that much

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from the code, you need to get IntVar that hold the value for Tc and P. Here is the new code:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import *
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk  
   
   
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Oxygen Fugacity')
root.geometry("500x400")

Tcinput = IntVar(master=root,value=1200)  # NEW
Pinput = IntVar(master=root,value=1)   # NEW

def some_func():
    global Tcinput, Pinput
    Tc = Tcinput.get() #  GETTER
    P = Pinput.get() #  GETTER
    a = str(round(fo2.NNO(Tc,P),2))
    b = str(round(fo2.FMQ(Tc,P),4))
    c = str(round(fo2.IW(Tc,P),4))
    d = str(round(fo2.MH(Tc,P),4))
    e = str(round(fo2.CoCoO(Tc,P),4))
    f = str(round(fo2.CCO(Tc,P),4))
    x=[a,b,c,d,e,f]
    return x

Temp_input = tk.Entry(root, width=15, borderwidth=5,textvariable=Tcinput)
Temp_input.grid(row=1,column=1)
P_input = tk.Entry(root, width=15, borderwidth=5,textvariable=Pinput)
P_input.grid(row=2,column=1)

Templabel = tk.Label(root,text='Temperature (C)').grid(row=1,column=0)
Plabel = tk.Label(root,text='Pressure (bar)').grid(row=2,column=0)

comp = tk.Button(root, text='Compute', command=lambda: some_func()).grid(row=3,column=1)

tk.Label(root, text='NNO').grid(row=1,column=3,padx=(30,0),pady=(10,10))
tk.Label(root, text='FMQ').grid(row=2,column=3,padx=(30,0),pady=(10,10))
tk.Label(root, text='IW').grid(row=3,column=3,padx=(30,0),pady=(10,10))
tk.Label(root, text='MH').grid(row=4,column=3,padx=(30,0),pady=(10,10))
tk.Label(root, text='CoCoO').grid(row=5,column=3,padx=(30,0),pady=(10,10))
tk.Label(root, text='CCO').grid(row=6,column=3,padx=(30,0),pady=(10,10))

NNO_OUT = tk.Message(root, text = some_func()[0]).grid(row=1,column=4,padx=(30,0))
FMQ_OUT = tk.Message(root, text = some_func()[1]).grid(row=2,column=4,padx=(30,0))
IW_OUT = tk.Message(root, text = some_func()[2]).grid(row=3,column=4,padx=(30,0))
MH_OUT = tk.Message(root, text = some_func()[3]).grid(row=4,column=4,padx=(30,0))
CoCoO_OUT = tk.Message(root, text = some_func()[4]).grid(row=5,column=4,padx=(30,0))
CCO_OUT = tk.Message(root, text = some_func()[5]).grid(row=6,column=4,padx=(30,0))



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You know that button isn't going to do anything right?

Comment: Also the `all(Tcinput,Pinput)` isn't going to use the `all` function that you defined. Instead it will use python's built in `all` function.

Comment: yeah you're right, I adjusted the solution.

Comment: Hey @TheLizzard, this may be a stupid question. How can I make the button work? you're right, the button does sweet FA :(

Comment: @EdwardBaker There are very few stupid questions and this one isn't one of them. In this answer the code gets *stuck* at `root.mainloop()` so the function `some_func` is never defined as python's code execution doesn't reach that part of the code. Move the function definition just after the import statements and the button should work

Comment: fixed to reflect comment

Comment: @YousefZ01 You know that you are using `Tcinput.get()` even before it is even shown on the screen when you do `tk.Message(..., text=some_func()[0]).grid(...)`. I really don't think that is what OP wants.

Comment: I'm doing it in the function though, so when he triggers it, it'll activate the function and then get it, meaning that it is shown on the screen?

Comment: Ive moved the some_func definition up and the button still doesn't work, I've tried messing around with lambda and using ()'s on the function, which some of the answers to this problem have suggested. Any more ideas? @TheLizzard